# Widevine DRM - Body request payload

Tags: video, drm, widevine, eme

I'm working on the integration of a player which have to play streams secured with Widevine DRM in a browser.

I've checked some well-known players :

- DashJs - https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki
- ShakaPlayer - https://github.com/google/shaka-player

Fortunately, these players provide some samples of stream secured using Widevine DRM.

My question concerns the XHR executes to retrieve DRM Key. In any Widevine secured stream, I can see (in devtools) at least 2 XHR targeting the license server.

Let's take an example: https://media.axprod.net/TestVectors/v7-MultiDRM-SingleKey/Manifest_1080p.mpd

This stream is available in :

- DashJs (https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html) : "Axinom Test Content (modern) > 1080p with PlayReady and Widevine DRM, single key"
- ShakaPlayer (https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/) : "Axinom > Multi-DRM"

On Chrome (65.0.3325.181) when I load the stream I can 2 XHR (let's omit the pre-flight "OPTIONS" xhr) :

- POST `https://drm-widevine-licensing.axtest.net/AcquireLicense`

  - Request `X-AxDRM-Message` header specific to Axinom
  - Request `Content-Length: 2`
  - A Request Payload equals to `\x08\x04` (Right click on XHR, then "Copy as cURL" and paste it in any text editor)
  - Response `Content-Length: 706`
- POST `https://drm-widevine-licensing.axtest.net/AcquireLicense`

  - Request `X-AxDRM-Message` header specific to Axinom
  - Request `Content-Length: 3929`
  - A Request Payload with a certain amount of data
  - Response `Content-Length: 426`

I don't get why there is 2 XHR?
Moreover, the first XHR with the two characters `\x08\x04` is always sent no matter the stream selected (in case of Widevine DRM stream), is there a specific meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first request is for the Widevine service certificate

The second request is the actual License request

You can read more about this on [https://www.widevine.com/product_news.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170527133907/https://www.widevine.com/product_news.html#chrome20170502)

See the section `Update - Chrome 59 and Service Certificates`

Comment: Thanks @digitalPBK, indeed I finally found this documentation : https://storage.googleapis.com/wvdocs/Widevine_DRM_Proxy_Integration.pdf


In the part "Using Service Certificates" they talk about :

"It is highly recommended that the service certificate workflow is supported in all proxy implementations. The sample proxy scripts provide code examples on how to support this request.".


And this is the first request : Certificate retrieval.

Comment: Here's the archive link, since he original is now dead http://web.archive.org/web/20180214001759/https://www.widevine.com/product_news.html

Comment: awesome, I noticed the same but didn't know what they are, thankyou @digitalPBK
though, do you know how to decode the content of the response? or are they intentially encrypted as is and not human-readable? Im trying to have our own license server, maybe you can advice

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a specific meaning to the first request. But the exact meaning is not public knowledge. It will require you to get in touch with Widevine and get CWIP certification.

Comment: This could explain why I cannot find any information about these requests :( Thanks for the tips